# Portamento in the Scream Tracker

Tags: midi, pitch

I am designing the implementation of the [Scream Tracker 2](https://gist.github.com/bryc/d7881b732c72f4330bd5f11060200079) using Midi math. Everything matched perfect so far, until I considered "portamento". In the sci-pop articles there's no much technical info on the portamento, Scream tracker doc says

```
    E - Portamento up. This command slides the notes pitch
        up by a specified amount.
    F - Portamento down.
```

which also does not help.

I implemented this note pitch change as linear change to the sampling frequency, and was very surprised to find out that it is not the case in Scream tracker applications - the "portamento" does not have linear sampling frequency change. Looking into the code I see the cause of this - the sampling interval is calculated as 0x2260027/pitch/machine_speed and consists of two parts - whole part and fractional part, therefore it is normal within this algorithm that "portamento" has higher sampling frequency step at higher pitches.

Question: is there any technical information on what "portamento" is and how its frequency curve must look like?

**Update:** I was [successful with the implementation](https://youtu.be/djufFWFpG8c); the Midi math was very useful, but requires additional feature - log2 calculation for the period to map it onto the Midi pitch scale. I have put it into hardware thus calculation takes microsecond.

Comment: What is "Midi math"? And why do you want to do ScreamTracker 2 specifically, and not ProTracker, ScreamTracker 3 (S3M) or FastTracker 2 (XM), for which there is a large amount of music available? And by the way, there's an ST2 replayer with source available, did you look at this https://github.com/viiri/st2play  It claims to be an accurate reproduction.

Comment: I was designing Midi before, and reusing its hardware accelerated math. I do not have definite answer to this question, maybe because I still have some modules and is familiar with STM from 90s, and STM player is not yet existent for the target platform. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If this is for OPL4, then S3M might be a particularly interesting choice, because it supports both PCM and FM at the same time.

Comment: Probably after implementation of ST2/STM.

Comment: Staying within ProTracker and Amiga pitch limitations, with a lookup table of less than 2 kilobytes it would be possible to map all possible Amiga period values to an OPL4 F_NUMBER + Octave, 10+4 bits per pitch, about 900 entries in the table.

Comment: Not that simple. Tracker period can be translated with look-up table (I made log2 in 4+16 bits calculation as a tech challenge :) ), I empirically found out that direct translation of the resulting pitch to the octave/fnum is wrong way doing, the resulting oct/fnum must be log-curved like for Midi therefore there's another related lookup table of 0x600 entries (3kb).

Comment: Do you mean the snd_opl4_pitch_map[0x600] table from opl4_synth.c in Linux/ALSA drivers, and also by the name "ms_wave_pitch_map" in ms2.c MoonSound routines by Avelino Herrera Morales? That translation could be baked into the period->F_NUMBER+Octave mapping table, only storing the final result for each period value in the table, around 900 entries for full ProTracker pitch range. But if you need a cents-to-OPL4 frequency mapping for some other purposes as well, then it's probably needed.

Comment: Maybe it isn't relevant anymore since you got it working, but to translate a PAL Amiga period value P straight to OPL4 octave and F_NUMBER, the calculation is:  

 ratio = (3546895 / P ) / 44100;
 ratio_semitones = log(ratio) / log(2^(1/12));
 octave = floor(ratio_semitones/12)+1;
 f_number = round(2^(ratio_semitones/12-(octave-1)+10)-1024);

and the ms_wave_pitch_map table has been made like this: 
ms_wave_pitch_map[i] = round(2^((i/128)/12+10)-1024);

Comment: Or you could go straight to octaves and leave out the semitone thing and dividing by 12, like ratio_octaves = log2((3546895 / P ) / 44100); But it's nice to see the semitones.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I can not find a decent collection of the S3M music. Got two modules by FC for 2nd reality - the ones I have heard before.

Comment: Do you mean any kind of S3M music, or something with both FM and PCM? AFAIK, the FM+PCM combination is quite rare and obscure, that's why I suggested it. For the MSX, ScreamTracker 3 might enable making much better OPL4 music than any existing trackers. For general S3M music, check AMP, Purple Motion: https://amp.dascene.net/detail.php?detail=modules&view=5984   Skaven: https://amp.dascene.net/detail.php?detail=modules&view=6706       Cybelius: https://amp.dascene.net/detail.php?detail=modules&view=1420          Dune: https://amp.dascene.net/detail.php?detail=modules&view=2313

Comment: Waypoint by Dune from 1995, one of my all-time favourites, a wonderful tune https://amp.dascene.net/downmod.php?index=16908

Comment: Looking at TECH.DOC in Scream Tracker 3's distribution archive scrmt321.zip, it looks like ScreamTracker uses 3579264 Hz as its "Amiga audio clock", which is close to the NTSC rate 3579545. Scream Tracker 3's own internal rate is 3579264 * 4 = 14317056, and ST3 period values are Amiga periods * 4. Converting that to OPL4 gives st3_to_opl4_note_ratio_oct = log2((14317056 / note_st3period) / 44100); octave = floor(st3_to_opl4_note_ratio_oct)+1;
f_number = round(2^(st3_to_opl4_note_ratio_oct-(octave-1)+10)-1024);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scream Tracker is one of the first, if not *the* first, early PC clones of Amiga tracker music replayers, and I assume it attempts to replicate ProTracker's behavior at least to some extent. The linked [ScreamTracker manual](https://gist.github.com/bryc/d7881b732c72f4330bd5f11060200079) says "*Lx,M,N - ProTracker commands converted, but not implemented*", which suggests that the other commands that have been implemented, try to be ProTracker compatible.

ProTracker itself is based on Karsten Obarski's Ultimate Soundtracker from 1987/88, and to understand how trackers work, it is necessary to understand how the Amiga hardware, particularly the Paula chip works, and how the replayer routines are structured. If you want to try reading actual ProTracker playroutine code, check [the source for the CIA timing version of 2.3A](http://16-bits.org/pt_src/replayer/PT2.3a_replay_cia.s).

Quote from https://www.exotica.org.uk/wiki/Protracker
:

> On a PAL Amiga, the clock is 3546895 Hz, so a period of 428 plays at 3546895 / 428 = 8287.13 Hz.

The "period" number means how many clock cycles Paula waits before moving to the next sample. The smaller the period number is, the faster Paula proceeds through sample data and the higher the pitch of the produced sound. The highest practical rate (limited by audio DMA speed) and minimum period number is 124, which gives an output sample rate of about 28.6 kHz. See https://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=70783

Why are the period tables like that? It's my speculation, but I think the period numbers (see mt_PeriodTable in the PT2.3a replay routine) have been selected so that sample loops of lengths that are powers of 2 produce good notes for standard tuning, but using the NTSC model's 3579545 Hz rate instead of the PAL clock rate. For example, a loop of 32 samples and period value 254, which is A-2 in ProTracker, produces a sound with a fundamental frequency at 3579545 / (254 * 32) = 440.40 Hz. With the PAL rate, we get 436.38 Hz for tuning 0 A-2, while a period value 252 would yield 439.84 Hz, much closer to 440 Hz. 252 is not found in any of the finetune tables, so things aren't tuned for Europeans, despite all the software authors being from Europe. :) So if you wonder why playing along Amiga chiptunes with your A=440Hz tuned instrument sounds a bit out of tune, this is why.

The Portamento command in ProTracker modules is based on manipulating the period number at "vblank rate", and this can be done with simple addition instructions. Other kinds of portamento would require more difficult calculations.

In the basic scenario, the tracker playroutine is executed once every screen refresh i.e. 50 times a second on a PAL machine. If "CIA tempo" is used, the playroutine timing is not tied to screen refresh but a programmable timer interrupt. The portamento command's speed parameter says, how much the period number is increased or decreased at every interrupt i.e. playroutine invocation i.e. tick. Portamento and tone portamento speed of 1 means changing the period value by 1 at every vertical screen refresh or CIA timer interrupt. Well, actually, not *every* playroutine invocation - in Amiga ProTracker replayers, portamento is *not* processed on the *first* tick of every pattern row, only on subsequent ticks. Only effects 9, B, C, D, E and F are processed on the first tick (see the mt_CheckMoreEfx routine). This means that with the default vblank tempo/speed of 6 ticks per row, portamento is updated *5 times* per row, and with speed 1 set with tempo command F01, portamento is updated 0 times per row and no actual portamento sliding happens at all.

To reproduce Amiga (SoundTracker, ProTracker etc) pitch and portamento correctly, you'll have to keep track of the current pitch in terms of period numbers. Having pitches in Hz cannot be your master information. Each channel's current pitch needs to be a period i.e. master-clock-divider number. The lower the pitch, the more relative accuracy you have, and vice versa. For low bass notes, portamento is "slower". You might notice this in how composers have used higher portamento speeds and vibrato depths for low notes than for high notes in actual songs. For the highest ProTracker notes, the difference in period numbers between consecutive semitones is only something like 8 units. In "finetune" 0 period table, G-3's period number is 143 and G#3 is 135, meaning that the pitch resolution is only 8 possible different pitches per semitone. But in the low range, C-1 is 856 and C#1 is 808, so you need to take much wider portamento steps to get from one note to another.

ScreamTracker is originally about being able to play Amiga style music on a PC and a single-channel audio output such as SoundBlaster or a "Covox" DAC. That's why there's the added complexity of the audio output sampling rate, which could be for example 16 kHz, for a PC from that era. But to play tracker modules i.e. songs correctly, you'll have to divide the structure of your playroutine so that you emulate there being a "vertical refresh interrupt" e.g. 50 times per second.

To understand how everything works and what ScreamTracker tried to replicate, it's good to look at Amiga replayer routines, and maybe know a bit about computing "back in the day". Like if you study the Bible, you'll have to know ancient Hebrew and Greek and other such things, or so I've heard. For studying Amiga and ProTracker, it's good to be able to read Motorola 68000 assembly. ;) Whatever there is in early ScreamTrackers, is some kind of a translation of Amiga things over to PC land. I'm sure ScreamTracker did not get all the details 100% right and it's not fully ProTracker compatible - no PC replayer ever got everything 100% right. However, with ScreamTracker 3 and S3M modules, things are different and it's not meaningful to compare specific behavior details with ProTracker, because ST3 extends the capabilities so much and stands on its own.

What comes to ScreamTracker's portamento implementation specifically, looking at the manual, it seems to approximate the behavior of the original Amiga playroutines, without trying to replicate the structure of the 68000 program code. The portamento speed calculation formula "TEMPO/10 - 1", where "tempo" is probably Amiga vblank speed * 10, produces an approximation of what happens in Amiga replayers. The "-1" part must have been added in order to simulate the Amiga playroutine's not actually doing any adding or subtracting on the *first* tick of each row, so speed 6 (vblanks per row) means portamento sliding rate of 5 pitch changes per row. Quote from the Scream Tracker manual

```
... For every row, these commands will
be run by TEMPO/10-1 times. For example if tempo is 60, the volume
slide will be run 5 times, which means that command D02 slides
the volume down 5*2=10 units every row.
```

Having tempo multiplied by 10 looks like an attempt to bake both vblank tempo ("speed") and BPM tempo (CIA tempo) expressivity in the same number.

Comment: "TEMPO/10-1" is incorrect and misleading in this manual. It must say "TEMPO/10h-1", with higher tempo's nibble used as counter for the tunings. For tempo 60 (hex!) number of tunings is 60h/10h-1=5. For tempo 5fh number of tunings is 4.

Comment: @Anonymous That's weird. I haven't really used ScreamTracker, so all I know is what's in the manual. I think it's possible that some of that stuff is based on reverse engineering and guessing, or just re-inventing. Some things in ProTracker are really worth re-inventing and re-doing, but the tempo system isn't near the top of the list.